# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP except for one directory

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I apologize for asking a question that has been asked in various other forms, but none of the answers I've came across work for my particular situation.

I want to redirect all pages to HTTP (via mod_rewrite), unless they are in the /secure/ folder.

Here's what I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^secure 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Another version that someone claimed worked, but doesn't work in this case:

```
RewriteRule  ^secure/  -  [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.thevirtualstagingexperts.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I'd rather use a variation of the first version. It looks like it should work (to me anyway). Can anyone shine some line on this o so dreary subject?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of https, especially if the client explicitly asked for it?

Comment: I only want to use HTTPS for the checkout process, which is in the /secure/ folder. The rest of the website doesn't need to be browsed in HTTPS.

Comment: I'm using absolute links to go from one to the other, but I'd like to have a rule just in case.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question to be more easily understandable. Why don't you want them to use HTTPS on the non-checkout part of your website? I understand that you don't want to require it, but why prevent it?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter. They're on shared hosting and I didn't want to bog down the server any more than was necessary.

Comment: I was more wondering why the first version of that rule doesn't work. I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Ok, that's a good goal, but I wouldn't recommend using this until you've benchmarked this, as depending on your setup, HTTPS could mean a huge hit or a tiny one (see http://serverfault.com/questions/43692/how-much-of-a-performance-hit-for-https-vs-http-for-apache).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was pointed out to me that HTTPS doesn't tax Apache as much as I thought. Apparently the majority of the extra load comes in establishing the connection. Since the client will already have established the secure connection at this point, it should be fine to let them continue with it.

If anyone who reads this knows why the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^secure 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

doesn't work (it doesn't exclude the /secure/ directory like it should), I would love to know. I'm new to programming and not being able to understand something like this really gets under my skin.

Thank you Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Re: *Here is what I tried*

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^secure 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I think you're missing a slash on that URI:  `^/secure`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secure/.*
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original solution worked for me, after adding a `[R,L]` to the last rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^secure 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%{HTTP_HOST} !\.dev$ [NC]%{HTTP_HOST} ^www\..+$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since your answer may be a good answer, it still needs more explanation about the changes and how it works.